Efficiently Loading Pickle Objects Using cudf
I have a file Large_File.pkl that I would like load as a cudf.DataFrame object. However, it seems like there is no direct pandas.read_pickle() alternatives in cudf.
The work-around I have found so far is to load the pickle object first as a pandas.DataFrame object then convert it to a cudf.DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
import cudf

# Load the pickle file into a pandas DataFrame
pd_dataframe = pd.read_pickle('Large_File.pkl')

# Convert the pandas DataFrame to a cuDF DataFrame
cudf_dataframe = cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas(pd_dataframe)

I am wondering whether there are more memory-efficient solutions to this problem?

This is probably the best approach if you can't change your file format going forward. If you can, I'd recommend considering Parquet or something similar, depending on your data.
